# Mudar Videos da Tela

Tags: javascript

Bom Pessoal eu tenho um tela que incorpora vídeos do Youtube

```
<div class="row centro-video">
  <iframe width="853" height="480"  class="fundo-video" id="video-curso1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kRUyL6cJ7W4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Estou carregando uma lista de videos do banco de dados, que possui o título do vídeo, e o link do vídeo, estou criando um botão pra cada vídeo.

```
<?php
  foreach ($listaVideo as $videoobj) {
?>
  <a href="<?php echo $videoobj->getLink()?>" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-block btn-primary texto-grande" type="button"> <?php echo $videoobj->getTitulo()?></a>
<?php
  }
?>
```

A duvida é a seguinte, como faço para mudar o vídeo do IFRAME quando o botão for clicado ? com javascript ou jquery

Comment: O que você deseja seria alterar o a fonte (`src`) do vídeo ao clicar em um botão?

Comment: eu queria mudar o link do iframe, com o link que to pegando do banco no caso na parte $videoobj->getLink()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso, basta fazer uma função que altere o atributo `src` do iframe, exemplo:

```js
function changeVideo($a) {
  document.getElementById('video-curso1').src = $a.href;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kRUyL6cJ7W4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" onclick="return changeVideo(this)">Video 1</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cHupkv2cEhs?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" onclick="return changeVideo(this)">Video 2</a>
<div class="row centro-video">
  <iframe width="853" height="480" class="fundo-video" id="video-curso1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kRUyL6cJ7W4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Certo, mas vc percebeu que os botões estão sendo criado a partir de um for, eu quero saber como vou recuperar cada link desse, sendo do referido botão que foi clicado

Comment: Alterei o exemplo para receber o link do atributo href da tag <a>, como no seu código. Então você só precisa adicionar o evento onclick conforme o exemplo

Comment: Era isso mesmo, agora funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Faça com que os botões alterem o atributo 'src' do iframe, veja (note que eu setei um id ao iframe):

Jquery:

```
$("#idiframe").attr("src", "linkvideo");
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('idiframe').src ='linkvideo';
```

@Edit: Pra chegar no que você quer, substitua o atributo href do link pra '#' ficando assim

```
<a href="#">
```

Após fazer isso atribua o código que eu lhe passei à uma função, pra evitar o repetimento de código.

```
function mudarVideo(url){
    document.getElementById('idiframe').src = url;
}
```

Nos botões sendo criados pelo laço for, acrescente o seguinte atributo:

```
onclick="mudarVideo('<?php echo $videoobj->getLink();?>');?>"
```

Ficando no final desse jeito:

```
<?php
    foreach ($listaVideo as $videoobj) {
?>
    <a href="#" onclick="mudarVideo('<?php echo $videoobj->getLink();?>');?>"  data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-block btn-primary texto-grande" type="button"> <?php echo $videoobj->getTitulo()?></a>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Deve resolver seu problema...

Comment: sim certo, mas como eu vou pegar os links dos videos, se estou criando os botões a partir de um for, eles n vão ter id definido

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você está criando os botões a partir de um for, e eles não vão ter id definido, mas, os botões não precisam de um id, apenas o iframe.

Comment: Certo, mas como vou trocar o src do iframe, se não tenho como capturar o botão

Comment: Editei o post, leia e me fale se resolveu.

Comment: Era isso mesmo valeu